# Mouse over events with path in a grid don't work as expected, wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a grid with a viewbox and a path in it. I want on grid mouse over to change the fill of the path. But the mouse over fires only when directly over a path, `it ignores the grid`.

I looked all over the web, but i couldn't find anywhere where this problem is mentioned.

xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="15" x:Name="gdOpenBrowser">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenBrowserCursorCommand}" 
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=gdOpenBrowser}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoginButtonCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-10" Y="-5"/>
                    </Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                    <Path Fill="White" Data="M38 8H10c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4v24c0 2.21 1.79 4 4 4h8v-4h-8V16h28v20h-8v4h8c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4V12c0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4zM24 20l-8 8h6v12h4V28h6l-8-8z"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
```

[image: When on path, it works]
[image: When not, but still in a grid, it doesn't work]
[image: The grid]

Comment: Try setting `Background` is the `Grid` to transparent for example. When it's not initialised it's not hit test visible

Comment: yup, that's it, Answer the question so i can accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment if you want whole `Grid` to be hit test visible you need to initialize `Background` property of the `Grid` with some brush, for example `Transparent` which will have same visual effect as `null` but will make whole `Grid` hit test visible.

```xml
<Grid ... x:Name="gdOpenBrowser" Background="Transparent">
```